# How can I tell if a streamwriter is closed?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr, backgroundworker, streamwriter

I'm using a streamwriter in combination with a background worker, for logging.

As such, I have

```
System::Void
MyUI::execBWorker_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {

String^ outputPath = _clr::Settings::ApplicationLogPath("_log.txt", true, false);
logfile_ = gcnew StreamWriter(outputPath,true);

DoStuff();
logfile_->Close();
}
```

Things in the DoStuff() method raise the Progress event.

```
System::Void
MyUI::execBWorker_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {
logfile_->WriteLine("something");
}
```

I think this really smells.  How can I make it better, or at least how can I check the logfile hasn't been closed?  There are a lot of messages, so I'm concerned about opening and closing the logfile continuously.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the `StreamWriter` is closed, the `BaseStream` property will return `null`.

Comment: Cool - answers the technical part.

Comment: @Melanie: `File::AppendText` might be useful in your case.

Comment: This answer is wrong - for me it did not return null and Resharper is also also warning me that (streamWriter.BaseStream != null) is always true.

Comment: @Trojaner On .NET desktop this is the case. Are you using something else?

Comment: @Trojanerand does in .NET Core too https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L215

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: @leppie Your link is dead, correct permalink: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/c8ab9ee7f144dd8b42762a06ffd9d9b40b918490/src/mscorlib/shared/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L215

Comment: In my case, using .net 6 console, `StreamWriter.BaseStream` will never be null, I use the readonly property `StreamWriter.BaseStream.CanSeek = false` to determine if the stream is closed